# How to set a number not in submatrix of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array. I want to set 0 to the indexes NOT in the submatrix mask.

```
import numpy as np

mtrx = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
mask = mtrx[1:4, 1:4]
```

Of course this is wrong:

```
mtrx[~mask] = 0
```

The result I want:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  6  7  8  0]
 [ 0 11 12 13  0]
 [ 0 16 17 18  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: But mask is not a boolean array in your case. It's a slice off the data array. Can you specify clearly what are the inputs?

Comment: The indexes of the mask.

Comment: Then, one way would be - `mtrx.flat[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(mtrx.size),mask)] = 0`.

Comment: Make mask so `mask = np.ones(mtrx.shape).astype(bool); mask[1:4, 1:4] = False` then mtrx[mask] and mtrx[~mask] will work

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to index an array of zeros and add the values from the original array indexed:

```
s = np.s_[1:4,1:4]
out = np.zeros_like(mtrx)
out[s] = mtrx[s]
```

---

```
print(out)

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 0., 11., 12., 13.,  0.],
       [ 0., 16., 17., 18.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: AFAIK `np.s_` does create tuples if more than one index is specified, so no need to cast. But apart from that this looks like the right approach to me. Also, you can use `zeros_like(mtrx)` this sets the shape and the dtype. And you needn't add, just copying is probably cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the matrix by a mask such as:

```py
import numpy as np
mtrx = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
mask = np.zeros((5,5))
mask[1:4,1:4] = 1

mask
>>>array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

mtrx * mask
>>> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
           [ 0., 11., 12., 13.,  0.],
           [ 0., 16., 17., 18.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the rows and columns to zeros.

```
   import numpy as np

    mtrx = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
    mtrx[:1] = 0
    mtrx[-1:] = 0
    mtrx[:,:1] = 0
    mtrx[:, -1:] = 0 
    print(mtrx)
    #output
    #[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
    # [ 0  6  7  8  0]
    # [ 0 11 12 13  0]
    # [ 0 16 17 18  0]
    # [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: What if the matrix is much larger?

Comment: Instead of creating and adding/multiplying with other matrix, this will be better according to me

Comment: Again, what if `mtrx` has a shape of (1000,1000) for instance...?

Comment: It will make outer rows/columns to zero.

Comment: The point of my question is what if it is only a few rows/cols that should be non zero...

Comment: Can Change the number of rows/columns to make zero instead of 1.